# Reconstruct certificate chain using AIA Fetching?

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509

I am trying to use AIA fetching to reconstruct a certificate chain, but only leaf certificates have a valid URIs. All intermediate nodes that I tested on either the CA Issuer is missing(facebook) or the URI returned 404.

[At the time of this article](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/aia-fetching/) AIA fetching was valid.

My questions are: Is AIA fetching still working? If not, is there any chance that I can reconstruct the whole certificate chain if I only have the leaf certificate?

Comment: There is almost certainly a bug in your code. I was able to download the intermediate certificate for facebook by dereferencing the URI in the AIA extension.

Comment: How is that even possible? THE CA Issuer is 'http://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertSHA2HighAssuranceServerCA.crt' and when I download it I get the following response: 'b'<html>\r\n<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'.  EDIT: Actually, you are right. The problem was that my URI had a \n

Comment: Glad you got it to work. I would like to thank you for bringing AIA fetching to my attention, I didn't even know that was a thing.

Answer (score 2):

I just realized there was a bug in my code and I was introducing a '\n' at the end of the URI. Don't be me, guys.